# The jstring arguments are passed as nil in JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, android-studio-2.2

I have a code with two parts: Java and JNI-cpp. I have two separate cpp files and there one method for each. First I call Session.cpp and then calling Camera.cpp.

The two arguments are the same in the cpp methods.

You can see the Java part below:

```
// Sign in
    String
            username = ServiceModel.getInstance().getModelUsername(),
            password = ServiceModel.getInstance().getModelPassword(),
            licenceKey = ServiceModel.getInstance().getModelLicenceKey(),
            serviceIp = ServiceModel.getInstance().getModelCurrentServiceIp(),
            hashedPassword = md5(password);
    // Get session id
    String sessionId
            = signIn(username,
            hashedPassword,
            licenceKey,
            serviceIp); // Session Manager
    ServiceModel.getInstance().setModelSessionId(sessionId);
    // Get camera info
    HashMap<String, String> cameraDictionary
            = getCameraDictionary(sessionId,
            serviceIp); // Camera Manager
```

When I call signIn method everything works fine. The signIn method is written as below:

```
extern "C"
jstring
Java_com_company_mobile_StreamActivity_signIn(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject,
    jstring username,
    jstring password,
    jstring licenceKey,
    jstring serviceIp) {
std::string strServiceIp(env->GetStringUTFChars(serviceIp, NULL));
std::string serviceUrl = "http://" + strServiceIp + "/SessionManager";
SessionManager::IVSOSSessionManagerProxy proxy(serviceUrl.c_str());
std::string strUsername(env->GetStringUTFChars(username, NULL));
std::string strPassword(env->GetStringUTFChars(password, NULL));
std::string strLicenceKey(env->GetStringUTFChars(licenceKey, NULL));
std::string sId;
std::string &sessionId = sId;
if (proxy.signIn(strUsername,
strPassword,
strLicenceKey,
sessionId) == SOAP_OK) {
    return env->NewStringUTF(sessionId.c_str());
} else {
    return env->NewStringUTF("NO");
}
}
```

When I call getCameraDictionary method it fails in the first line. You can find the code below:

```
extern "C"
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>
Java_com_company_mobile_StreamActivity_getCameraDictionary(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject,
    jstring sessionId,
    jstring serviceIp) {
const char* serIp = env->GetStringUTFChars(sessionId, NULL);
std::string serviceUrl = "http://" + std::string(serIp) + "/EncoderManager";
std::string strSessionId(env->GetStringUTFChars(serviceIp, NULL));
CameraManager::ns__IVSOSEncoderContainerSOAPRef cc;
CameraManager::ns__IVSOSEncoderContainerSOAPRef &cameraContainer = cc;
CameraManager::IVSOSEncoderManagerProxy proxy(serviceUrl.c_str());
proxy.getAllCamera(strSessionId, cameraContainer);
std::string cameraName;
std::string cameraUrl;
std::string cameraUri;
std::string cameraUsername;
std::string cameraPassword;
std::string rtspUrl;
std::unordered_map <std::string, std::string> cameraDictionary;
if (cameraContainer.mObject.size() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cameraContainer.mObject.size(); i++) {
        cameraName = cameraContainer.mObject[i].mEncoderName;
        cameraUrl = cameraContainer.mObject[i].mEncoderIp;
        cameraUri = cameraContainer.mObject[i].mEncoderSecondaryRtsp;
        cameraUsername = cameraContainer.mObject[i].mEncoderUsername;
        cameraPassword = cameraContainer.mObject[i].mEncoderPassword;
        if (!(cameraUsername.size() > 0)) {
            rtspUrl = "rtsp://"
                      + cameraUsername
                      + ":"
                      + cameraPassword
                      + "@"
                      + cameraUrl
                      + cameraUri;
        } else {
            rtspUrl = "rtsp://"
                      + cameraUrl
                      + cameraUri;
        }
        cameraDictionary[cameraName] = rtspUrl;
    }
}
return cameraDictionary;
}
```

As I debugged I found the reason is that **the sessionId and the serviceIp are passed as NULL**. The method arises the problem is `GetStringUTFChars(sessionId, NULL)`. This method does not accept NULL value as the first parameter. However in the signIn method everything works fine. What can be the problem?

I tried many things including memory management issues or copying variables.

Comment: Once print sessionId and serviceIp in logcat.

Comment: For the Java part they have values. For the cpp part they are nil.